# Cannot get json data properly

Tags: android, web-services, api

I am using android volley to access my json data from my remote mysql database. Majority of the time it dont get any data, it always go into into response.errorlistener part, but sometime it work fine. Please tell me what is the most efficient way for accessing web services.

> 05-06 13:18:49.055 18409-18409/com.goworks.readyworks
>   D/CubicBezierInterpolator: CubicBezierInterpolator  mControlPoint1x =
>   0.2, mControlPoint1y = 0.65, mControlPoint2x = 0.28, mControlPoint2y = 0.97 05-06 13:18:49.055 18409-18409/com.goworks.readyworks D/CubicBezierInterpolator: CubicBezierInterpolator  mControlPoint1x =
>   0.2, mControlPoint1y = 0.65, mControlPoint2x = 0.28, mControlPoint2y = 0.97 05-06 13:18:49.055 18409-18409/com.goworks.readyworks D/CubicBezierInterpolator: CubicBezierInterpolator  mControlPoint1x =
>   0.2, mControlPoint1y = 0.65, mControlPoint2x = 0.28, mControlPoint2y = 0.97 05-06 13:18:49.055 18409-18409/com.goworks.readyworks D/CubicBezierInterpolator: CubicBezierInterpolator  mControlPoint1x =
>   0.2, mControlPoint1y = 0.65, mControlPoint2x = 0.28, mControlPoint2y = 0.97 05-06 13:18:49.085 18409-18805/com.goworks.readyworks E/Volley: [569] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that
>   has not called Looper.prepare()
>                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that
>   has not called Looper.prepare()
>                                                                       at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:200)
>                                                                       at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:114)
>                                                                       at android.widget.Toast$TN.(Toast.java:342)
>                                                                       at android.widget.Toast.(Toast.java:99)
>                                                                       at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:248)
>                                                                       at com.goworks.readyworks.RegisterActivity$5.getParams(RegisterActivity.java:314)
>                                                                       at com.android.volley.Request.getBody(Request.java:468)
>                                                                       at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.addBodyIfExists(HurlStack.java:253)
>                                                                       at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.setConnectionParametersForRequest(HurlStack.java:227)
>                                                                       at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:107)
>                                                                       at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:97)
>                                                                       at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:114)
>   05-06 13:18:49.235 18409-18409/com.goworks.readyworks
>   E/Registration Error:: com.android.volley.VolleyError:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that
>   has not called Looper.prepare()

```
if (isValidated()) {

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(RegisterActivity.this);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            pDialog.setTitle("Making a member");
            pDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();

            userUsername = uname.getText().toString();
            userPassword = pass.getText().toString();
            emailAddress = email.getText().toString();
            userAddress = address.getText().toString();
            userContact = contact.getText().toString();

            StringRequest stringrequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url + "registration.php",
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            try {

                                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                                String code = jsonObject.getString("code");
                                String message = jsonObject.getString("message");

                                if (code.equals("reg_success")) {
                                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    pDialog.cancel();
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();

                                } else if (code.equals("reg_failed")) {
//                                    Snackbar.make(v, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
                                    pDialog.cancel();
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Not Registered",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }


                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong, Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                    Snackbar.make(v, "Something went wrong, Please try again", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
                    pDialog.cancel();
                    Log.e("Registration Error:", String.valueOf(error));
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    params.put("username", userUsername);
                    params.put("password", userPassword);
                    params.put("email", emailAddress);
                    params.put("contact", userContact);
                    params.put("address", userAddress);
                    params.put("location", finalCoords);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Delievered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    return params;
                }
            };

            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
            requestQueue.add(stringrequest);
        }
```

Comment: show code and share logcat

Comment: the problem is your remote mysql database.

Comment: it only giving issue in registration part. in login part and in other things it s working perfectly fine.

Comment: First of all check netconnection, second check URL, third check parameter must be same, and never attach null value in parameter. Hope this will help you

Comment: Just remove ` throws AuthFailureError ` and try it.

Comment: Still not working @NitinPatel

Comment: then better is check what is error?

Answer (score 0):

First of all check what is error by adding below code in `onErrorResponse(..){`

```
if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
Toast.makeText(context,"TimeoutError",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
    Toast.makeText(context,"NoConnectionError",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
    Toast.makeText(context,"AuthFailureError",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
    Toast.makeText(context,"ServerError",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
    Toast.makeText(context,"NetworkError",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
    Toast.makeText(context,"ParseError",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: what is response string?

Comment: Try this line in error what you get?  `Toast.makeText(context,error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: `java,lang.RuntimeException: Can`t create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`